# Not able to check checkbox built with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm building a table row with jQuery with checkboxes to perform actions like select and update / delete. However I'm not able click on the checkbox and select them.

```
for (var i = 0; i < newjsondata.length; i++) 
{
 tr = $('<tr/>');
 var checkbx = '<td><input type="checkbox" data-id="'+ newjsondata[i].id +'" id="select_ticket" name="select_ticket" class="select_ticket"/></td>';
 tr.append(checkbx);
}
```

However if I modify this code as below everything works fine, however the alignment is not good *(removing the "`<td>`" tag)*.

```
for (var i = 0; i < newjsondata.length; i++) 
{
 tr = $('<tr/>');
 var checkbx = '<input type="checkbox" data-id="'+ newjsondata[i].id +'" id="select_ticket" name="select_ticket" class="select_ticket"/>';
 tr.append(checkbx);
}
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Show all HTML file pls.

Comment: I don't have HTML. The above code generates the rows in a table.

Comment: Try adding an empty label to that. It might work. If you want more details let me know. I will send the answer.

Comment: empty label? where?

Comment: If option 2 is good. Then you can use Css, just set tr { text-align: center; }.

Comment: I don't get what happens with `tr`. You create a new `<tr>` tag in each iteration, append a checkbox to it, but how does it get included in the DOM?

Comment: I changed the code as below and its working now. However I'm not able to get the value of selected IDs in events like change or click.

var checkbx = '<td><input type="checkbox" class="select_ticket" data-id="'+ newjsondata[i].id +'" id="select_ticket" name="select_ticket"/></td>';
                          tr.append(checkbx);